# how to get php counter contents associated with variables

Tags: php

I have written a quiz script and it all works fine. What I want to do now is some fine tuning.

There are 6 questions. The questions and answers are defined in variables like this:

```
$q7="(7) __________ you like the red one or the blue one? (Positive, simple present)";
$a7="(7) <strong>Do</strong> you like the red one or the blue one? (Positive, simple present)";
```

As the person answers each question there is a counter that increments each correct answer.

I can view the counter and see that it contains the correct number of responses, but it is only a number.

If the person gets 3 out of 6 correct I show them the score like this -

```
You got 3/6 correct.
```

What I want to do is also show them the 3 correct answers they chose, and not the incorrect answers.

Is this possible? If the counter knows there are 3 correct answers, how do I get that info? Those particular variables?

How do I get this -
if $counter contains 4 or less correct answers then display those answers.

```
// *** question 12 *** //
print "<p>&nbsp;</p><table id='english_nb'><tr>";
print "<th>$q12</th></tr></table>";
print "<table id='english_nb'><tr>";
if ($_POST['answer12']==$do)
print "<td width='25%'><input type='radio' checked='checked' name='answer12' value='$do' />$do</td>";
else
print "<td width='25%'><input type='radio' name='answer12' value='$do' />$do</td>";
if ($_POST['answer12']==$didnt){
print "<td width='25%'><input type='radio' checked='checked' name='answer12' value='$didnt' />$didnt</td>";
$correct++;
}    
else
print "<td width='25%'><input type='radio' name='answer12' value='$didnt' />$didnt</td>";
if ($_POST['answer12']==$doesnt)
print "<td width='25%'><input type='radio' checked='checked' name='answer12' value='$doesnt' />$doesnt</td>";
else
print "<td width='25%'><input type='radio' name='answer12' value='$doesnt' />$doesnt</td>";
if ($_POST['answer12']==$did)
print "<td width='25%'><input type='radio' checked='checked' name='answer12' value='$did' />$did</td>";
else
print "<td width='25%'><input type='radio' name='answer12' value='$did' />$did</td>";
print "</tr></table>";
// *** check the answers *** //   
foreach ($_POST as $value){
if (isset ($value)){
$done++;
}
}
if ($done !=7) //set this to 1 higher than the number of questions and answers
print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Check answers' />";
if (($correct<5)&&($done==7)) //set this to the number of minimum correct answers
print "<p>You should review the information and try the quiz again.</p>";
    print "<p>Your score is $correct/6 correct.</p>"; //set this to the same number of questions and answers

    if (($done > 0)&&($done < 7)) //set this to 1 higher than the number of questions and answers
print "<p>You haven't answered all the questions. Please finish the quiz and re-submit your answers.</p>";
if(($done==7)&&($correct>4))
    { //set this to 1 higher than the number of questions and answers
print "<p>Your score is $correct/6 correct.</p>"; //set this to the same number of questions and answers
if ($correct==0)
$correct='0';
else 
    {
print "<p>The correct answers:</p>";
print "<p>$a7</p>"; 
print "<p>$a8</p>";
print "<p>$a9</p>";   
print "<p>$a10</p>";
print "<p>$a11</p>";
print "<p>$a12</p>";
```

Comment: `$a7` and `$q7`? You need to learn about arrays. `$a[1] = 'answer1'; $a[2] = 'answer2'`, etc...

Comment: better use `array()` instead of using variables, for example use an `array()` of questions and the other `array()` will contains the answers of each question.

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your code a lot, [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) would be a great start as others have said.

A simple way to do what you want could be adding a `$correctAnswers = "";` variable, and everytime you use `$correct++;` add `$correctAnswers .= "<p>$a1</p>";` and so on.

Then you could show them with `print $correctAnswers;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $q=array($q1,$q2,....);    //questions array
    $a=array($a1,$a2,....);    //answers array
    correctAnswer=array();     //array of correct answers. empty at start

    if (question=$q[0] && answer=$a[0]){  //if question and answer match 
      $correctAnswer[]=$a[0];   //adds the correct answer to the array
    }
    else{
       // do something if the q &a doesnt match
    }

    $correct_answer_count = count($correctAnswer);
```